# Unable to add avoid highways, tolls in Google Maps URL.

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to add two features of Google Maps in my app but I don't want to embed Google Maps Direction API. Here are they

1. Waypoints (Stops)
2. Avoid Highways, Tolls and Ferries.

If I use [Google Maps intent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#launch_turn-by-turn_navigation) then I can have 2nd option working but not the 1st. However if I use [Maps URL](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action), then I have 1st working but not the 2nd. 
How can I achieve both the features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Intent with old (`http://maps.google.com/maps`) Google Maps Directions URL scheme (for example for route from Naples, Italy to  Bari, Italy via Foggia and Zapponeta):

```
...
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Naples,Italy&daddr=Bari,Italy+to:Foggia,Italy+to:Zapponeta,Italy&dirflg=d,h"));
startActivity(intent);
...
```

Where:

`saddr` - tag for address (or coordinates) of route start;

`daddr` - tag address (or coordinates) of route end;

`+to:` - tag for address (or coordinates) of route waypoint (it can be several);

`dirflg` - tag for options. Can be: `d` - for driving travel mode, `w` - for walking travel mode, `r` - for public transport travel mode, `h` - for avoid highways route option, `t` - for avoid tolls route option. It can be set comma-separated (CSV).

For more details take a look at [this](https://moz.com/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters) article of [Pete Watson-Wailes](https://moz.com/community/users/21380). NB: some of URL parameters not working today (in 2018).

Comment: Worked like a charm. But one thing, why is this not included in latest version of Maps URL? And will there be any issue that might arise in future if I use this older intents like crashes or not working issues?

Comment: @NikhilKumar 1) don't know - it's really necessary feature; 2) don't know, probably, - so wrap calling Google Maps in separate method like `callGoogleMapsApp()` for make changes in one place, if it happens. But, seems many application use old URL scheme, so may be it will working some time. And usually Google shows a warning about the cancellation of some part of the API...

Comment: You are right. This is a necessary feature, don't know about Google why they didn't add this in latest version. Anyways thanks for your time and helping me. I will be using this one.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried [Directions URL](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action) on my android mobile phone and I see there's an options icon underneath the directions search boxes.

[image: options icon]

Comment: But I want to do that programmatically. I already know those options.